# Randomize Browser String Using Random User Agent for Firefox

Tags: agent

I have randonuseragent and refcontrol but I need a system that when firefox opens it chooses a random UA string.

If you think a script will work "IE" Greasemonkey.. I would need a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

"Secret Agent" might be the answer you require:

http://www.secretagent.org.uk/

or

https://www.dephormation.org.uk/index.php?page=81

Randomizes your user agent with every http request.

Disclosure: I wrote it.

Comment: Have a look at the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion You might want to give full disclosure if you're going to refer to something you're personally involved with.

Comment: Oops, sorry... yes I wrote it. Pete.